# Does someone know when was the FULL OUTER JOIN introduced into the standard SQL?

Tags: sql

Out of curiosity I would like to know roughly when was the FULL OUTER JOIN introduced into the standard SQL (ANSI SQL?).
I suppose mid 1980s?

Comment: It's at least mentioned in SQL1992 http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt

Comment: The 1st Standard from the mid-80s only had implicit join syntax, the explicit join syntax was added in SQL 92